# Assign pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Is possible to assign pointer to array or array to array?

```
int arr[3] {1,2,3};
int pnt[3];
pnt = arr;
//or
pnt = &arr[0];
```

compiler don't want accept this....

Comment: There are no pointers in the shown code. The variable `pnt` is an array, not a pointer, and arrays can't be assigned to.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is because arrays can *decay* to a pointer (to its first element)? That means plain `arr` in the right context will be equivalent to `&arr[0]`, and that will have the type "pointer to `int`", or `int *`. But even with the decay, an array *isn't* a pointer.

Comment: Change `int pnt[3];` to `int* pnt;` then both statements `pnt = arr;` and `pnt = &arr[0];` will work.

Comment: Also, `pnt = arr` *would* work if they were `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible to assign pointer to array

Yes.

> or array to array?

No. Arrays are not assignable.

> compiler don't want accept this....

That's because `pnt` is not a pointer. You can create a pointer to the first element of the array like this:

```
int* pnt = arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

> assign pointer to array

You can assign array to a pointer. E.g.:

```
int b[2] = {3,4};
int *p;
p=b;
```

Note, that in your case, you've tried to assign an array to another array, not a pointer. The variable p is still a pointer, but now happens to point to the place in memory, where the array b sits.

> or array to array

No, you can't do this. You could use std::array if you want this kind of syntax. In case of the raw array, like in the example, you'd have to copy the data from one array to another.